# How to disable the creation of core dump files in WebSphere

Tags: linux, websphere, coredump

When the WebSphere JVM is crashing, JVM is creating 10s of gigabytes of core dump,

Is there a way to disable the creation of core dump.

I changed the location of core dump by setting environment variable 
IBM_COREDIR

Please help to disable the coredump

Answer (score 4):

To disable specific java dumps you can use `-Xdump:<type>:none` or to disable all java dumps you can use `-Xdump:none`. See https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21242497 for more information and the different types that can be configured.  To disable core (system) dumps you would use `-Xdump:system:none`.  You didn't list what version of WebSphere you are using but the instructions for setting JVM arguments in each version of WebSphere can be found here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21417365.